# Apache2 not executing facebook's php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, apache

I have just started mingling with facebook's php sdk, but to no avail. Although php works fine for all the other stuff on my `ubuntu` instance, facebook's php sdk doesn't (i.e. php code is not executed). All dependencies (only `curl` and `json`) are enabled and working.

I tried to look into `/var/log/apache2/error.log` but it seems that the file is empty - but maybe I'm not looking in the correct place.

So my question is: what would be the steps for me to debug this problem! Thanks for helping a noob!

Here is the boilerplate index.php code for from facebook:

```
 <?php


require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'xxx',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

// This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

?>
```

Comment: How do you mean "code is not executed"? How are you instantiating the SDK? Without seeing the code you are using it's quite hard to tell what's wrong..

Comment: @Lix I am just using the example file given by facebook in the php sdk. I will paste the code if you want!

Comment: Yea - no need to show the sample code... Are you sure that this file is being requested? The only reason it would not be executed is if it is not being requested...

Comment: I'm starting to think it's on facebook's side, something about api access, will investigate and report back